# Wire up a UIScrollView with a UIView subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Ive got a UIView as a sub-view of UIScrollView, but cant fathom out how to reference to each different view to set its settings. For example I know I need to set the UIViews content size bigger than the UIScrollViews so scrolling can occur, but dont know where to put the code to set these values (can I do it in the main view controllers .m file? if so what is the syntax for referencing to these different views? do I have to give each view its own custom class to be able to do this?). Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create custom `class` for every `UIViews`, set the tag property for every view of `UIScrollView`'s `subView`.
Now if you have to do some modification in that different view, get it from scrollview, Like:

```
UIView *innerView  = [yourScrollView viewWithTag:yourViewTag];
```

Now you can add or remove any thing o this view, it will direct reflact to `scrollview`.